# Python mechanicalsoup Set Combobox Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

There is a dropdownlist in html page. I need to set value as I want using mechanicalsoup in Python. I tried this but it did not work.
If it's possible(I hope) how can i set a value in combobox. 
There is also another combobox (named combo2). the value of Combo2 depends on the value of Combo1. Combo1 refreshes Combo2.

```
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
url = 'https://www.webpage.com/main.jsp?page=Page2'
login_page = browser.get(url)
form = mechanicalsoup.Form(login_page.soup.find("form", {"name":"Form2"}))
input_data = {"Combo1": "02"}

<select name="Combo1" id="Combo1" onchange="fillMe('idoof', 'cName')" class="test">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="01">Apple</option>
<option value="02">Orange</option>
<option value="03">WaterMelon</option>
<option value="04">Grapefruit</option>
<option value="05">Pineapple</option>
<option value="06">Salad</option>
<option value="07">Tomato</option>
<option value="08">Beet</option>
</select>
```